# Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express и SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio

Пользуюсь Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express и появилась нужда подключиться к SVN репозиторию. В стандарте поддержки нет, официальным плагином Microsoft решила не баловать своих пользователей-программистов. Так как же быть? Может есть какие то официальные инструменты для работы в команде, если нет, то вопрос все тот же - как подключить SVN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio Express не поддерживает плагины. Поэтому возникают два варианта:

1. купить Visual Studio Professional и дополнить его плагинами: [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) (за деньги) или [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (бесплатно);
2. оставить Visual Studio Express и использовать [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) как самостоятельную систему версионного контроля.